# When creating a social voting system, should you keep track of downvotes and upvotes separately in the DB?

Tags: database, social-networking, voting

With things like SO, Digg, Reddit, etc...

Should one keep track of downvotes in the database independent of upvotes?  Or should they simply have a "votes" field that is decremented/incremented based off what the user does with no persisting of that?

How should votes be handled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On SO, up votes earn +10, down votes -2. For this to work they need to be tracked separately. It's quite possible for a controversial answer to generate a few of each, and just showing an aggregate number won't mean much. So I'd say keep them separate.

Comment: +1, exactly. Also need to stop re-voting and vote cancelling.

Answer (score 2):

I would keep them separate. Some questions have a lot of activity (up and down) and you really like to identify those.

Even if you are not interested in the difference right now, an extra field in the table is not that expensive, so it does not hurt to separate it. Because if you want to add it later, there is no way you can retrieve the data if it is not stored separately.

I also assume SO keeps separate votes for CW and non CW entries. Because if the question changes to CW later on, even with a recalc, the original gained/lost rep is kept.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you wish to do with your data.

If you only want to display votes than I say you only use one field. It's like number of views of a thread on forum. You want to see what gets most clicks, but not how many times someone viewed it.

Voting system on SO is a bit more complex. Since they can cancel all votes from particular user they have to keep track of **who** voted for/against **what**. This, I think, is written in another table, but because it is expensive to recalculate all votes every time someone views a question, they keep calculated value in a field, changing it whenever someone votes.

Answer (score 1):

I can advise you to store them separately maybe even with extra data who authored a particular up or downvote. Who knows, you may come up with a nice idea tomorrow and you will need this additional data to implement it.

But it would also be good to have a sort of pre-calculated field (let's call it cache) which is updated whenever an up- or a downvote is submitted. The pages will then be rendered with this precalculated field. This will increase the response time and lessen load on DB.

If it is too costy to recalculate values immediately you may consider runnning some scheduler tasks (once per hour?) which will process up-to-date votes and recalculate the cached values.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the amount of data you'll have in the database for social voting website the additional space for an extra `int` column to store down-votes is going to negligible so you'd be crazy not to.

Comment: You could realistically use a bit, instead of an int.  Over time, it actually adds up to a decent amount of space saving.  You wouldn't need another column, either.  If there is an entry in the table for a given user, the user has voted.  A value of 0 could be interpretted as being a downvote and a 1 could be interpreted as an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Well, given that SO has +10 for an upvote and -2 for a downvote, and there's recalculation occasionally going on, it would need to store them independently.

Otherwise an answer with 10 upvotes and 5 downvotes which originally gave you 90 points, this would recalc to 50 if they weren't stored separately.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep them separate so that I could review them separately. Socially, upvoting is very different to downvoting, and I'd want to be able to look at them independently if it were me.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely separately for one very simple reason. Tomorrow you'll want to do something extra that needs that information (some sort of report or graph for example). Besides keeping them separately costs you nothing.

Answer (score 0):

since people can usually vote once, and (in SO for example) can cancel their votes, you need to know who voted, at what time, what vote, and on which item.

Answer (score 0):

I am certain that the downvotes and upvotes are kept separately, though there could be an aggregate field that keeps the count. SO lets you change a vote later (make the downvote an upvote), and that's why I believe the votes are logged for each user too.